# Static struct in Rust

Tags: static, structure, rust

I'm playing with Nickel.rs to build a todo list example. As closures are not supported for the moment, I am trying to find another way deal with the simple structure I implemented.

Here is my code :

```
extern crate nickel;

use std::io::net::ip::Ipv4Addr;
use nickel::{Nickel, Request, Response};

struct TaskList {
    list: Vec<String>
}

impl TaskList {
    fn new() -> TaskList {
        TaskList { list: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn add_task (&mut self, task: &str) {
        &self.list.push(task.to_string());
    }

    fn get_tasks (&self) -> Vec<String> {
        self.list.to_vec()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();

    static mut sample : TaskList = TaskList { list: Vec::new() };

    sample.add_task("First");
    sample.add_task("Second");

    fn fetch_tasks (_request: &Request, response: &mut Response) {
        response.send(sample.get_tasks().to_string())
    }

    server.utilize(Nickel::static_files("./public"));

    server.get("/task", fetch_tasks);
    server.listen(Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), 6767);
}
```

But the compiler write me this : "mutable static items are not allowed to have destructors"

Do you have any advice on how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

If you want the TaskList to exist on the heap, use Box. However, stack scope should be valid event inside server.listen(), so I don't see why you'd need TaskList to be a static mut?

If you want to mess around with static variables, you have to do it unsafely, like this:

```
use std::mem::transmute;
use std::ptr;

struct Static {
  v: int
}

impl Static {
  fn whatever(&mut self) {
    println!("Write to static");
    self.v += 1;
  }
}

static mut _data:*const Static = 0 as *const Static;

unsafe fn get<'a>() -> &'a mut Static {
  if _data == ptr::null::<Static>() {

    // Notice this is a Box<Static>, which is a *Static allocated on the heap
    // transmute(Static { v: 0 }) wouldn't work because once the stack scope ends
    // the instance would no longer be valid; Box<T> lasts beyond the call to get()
    _data = transmute(box Static { v: 0 });
  }
  return transmute(_data);
}

unsafe fn release() {
  ptr::read::<Static>(_data);
}

impl Drop for Static {
  fn drop(&mut self) {
    println!("Dropped static");
  }
}

fn main() {
  unsafe {
    let foo = get();
    foo.whatever();
  }
  unsafe {
    let foo = get();
    foo.whatever();
  }
  unsafe {
    release();
  }
  println!("Done");
}
```

I really strongly recommend against it though, unless there's a very good reason.

Most of the time you can assume the a variable you create in one scope:

```
{
   let foo = Bar; 
   ...
} <-- End
```

Will continue to be valid until the end of that scope.

A sub call like server.get is still inside the main() { } scope where sample is defined.

It'll still be valid.

Comment: I assumed first that without making 'sample' variable static, it would be accessible in the function 'fetch_tasks' (because it's defined in the main() {}). But the compiler tells me I can't capture dynamic environment in 'fetch_task' so I have to use a closure. But router.get() needs a function for its 2nd parameter.

Comment: @ThomasC__ You probably need to use "middleware" so that you can access a handle to your `TaskList` given a `Request` context. Maybe check out some examples of middleware.